# Which of the Walking Statues does this art in the Waterdeep: Dragon Heist adventure depict?

Tags: published-adventures, lore, forgotten-realms, waterdeep-dragon-heist, art

The following art, [Walking Statue of Waterdeep by Sidharth Chaturvedi](https://www.deviantart.com/sidharthchaturvedi/art/DnD-Walking-Statue-of-Waterdeep-811396011), was made as interior art for the [*Waterdeep: Dragon Heist*](https://dnd.wizards.com/products/tabletop-games/rpg-products/dragonheist) adventure.

However, there doesn't seem to be any consensus in Reddit discussions on which of the Walking Statues this is. Which one is it?

[image: Two kids peer out of a high-up window in awe at an enormous moving statue kneeling in the middle of a sprawling village. The statue resembles a large muscular bearded man. Dust is pouring off it and forming a dust cloud.]

Comment: I went ahead and asked the artist in a comment on the linked dA post.

Comment: @V2Blast Feel free to update my answer if you hear back!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Most likely The Great Drunkard

These are the Walking Statues of Waterdeep:

- The God Catcher
- The Griffon
- The Sahuagin Humbled
- The Great Drunkard
- The Lady Dreaming
- The Honorable Knight
- The Hawkman
- The Swordmaiden

We can immediately rule some of these out by their descriptions or by images already presented in [Waterdeep: Dragon Heist](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/wdh/volos-waterdeep-enchiridion#TheWalkingStatues), leaving us with:

- <s>The God Catcher</s> [Image](https://media-waterdeep.cursecdn.com/attachments/thumbnails/4/345/850/578/9011.png) doesn't match
- <s>The Griffon</s> Not a griffon
- <s>The Sahuagin Humbled</s> Not a Sahuagin
- The Great Drunkard
- <s>The Lady Dreaming</s> Not a lady
- <s>The Honorable Knight</s> Not a knight in plate with sword and shield
- <s>The Hawkman</s> Not a hawk man
- <s>The Swordmaiden</s> Not a swordmaiden

Process of elimination yields **The Great Drunkard**. It's description gives some support as well:

> This walking statue stopped its rampage as it approached the Market, then fell backward and sat upon a building. When it settled, its arms fell limp at its sides and its head tilted forward onto its chest, giving the impression that it had fallen asleep.

While the arms aren't limp at the side, it does have the tilting head. And at the end of the day, this is just an artist's depiction of...something. Of the available options, this one is the only one that comes close.